# Value of optional type EKReminder not unwrapped

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, ios9, xcode7

I am trying to create reminder according to this tutorial, trying to change the Swift 1 to Swift 2 code:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iOS_8_Event_Kit_and_Swift_to_Create_Date_and_Location_Based_Reminders

I get the error: **Value for optional type not unwrapped.**

```
func createReminder() {

    if (appDelegate!.eventStore != nil) {
        let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: appDelegate!.eventStore) //value not unwrapped

        reminder.title = reminderText.text
        reminder.calendar =
            appDelegate!.eventStore!.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
        let date = myDatePicker.date
        let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: date)

        reminder.addAlarm(alarm)

        var error: NSError?
        appDelegate!.eventStore!.saveReminder(reminder,
            commit: true, error: &error)

        if error != nil {
            print("Reminder failed with error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the concept of optional value (variable can be not assigned a value at this point during run time), what I do not understand is that I am inside the if block, that checks the value for not being nil. Therefore appDelegate!.eventStore is not nil in this block, therefore does not need to be unwrapped (?). 
I also tried setting the "!" after this variable, like this:

```
appDelegate!.eventStore!
```

but it breaks other code, it gives error around this code:

```
appDelegate!.eventStore!.saveReminder(reminder,
            commit: true, error: &error)  //extra argumenr 'error' in call
```

Surrounding it with do{}catch{} statement does not help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the looks of it, this is more to do with the extra argument than with the implicitly unwrapped optional — Apple have updated a lot of their SDK for Swift 2, to avoid passing in the reference to the `NSError` object and use `try` instead.

```
eventStore.saveReminder(reminder, commit: true, error: &error)
```

becomes

```
do {
    try eventStore.saveReminder(reminder, commit: true)
}
catch error: NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

As a general rule, I avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals like the plague — there is very little need for them and when they do exist you can always make a proper non-optional. Try:

```
func createReminder() throws {

    guard let eventStore = appDelegate?.eventStore else {
        let error: NSError = NSError(domain: "com.mycompany.myapp", code: 1, userInfo: [
        NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to get event store from app delegate"
        ])
        throw error
    }

    let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: eventStore)

    reminder.title = reminderText.text
    reminder.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewReminders()
    let date = myDatePicker.date
    let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: date)

    reminder.addAlarm(alarm)

    try eventStore.saveReminder(reminder, commit: true)
}
```

That way you are not playing around with implicitly unwrapped optionals, `eventStore` is guaranteed to be set when you use it and whatever calls `createReminder()` can handle the error is there is one (you would probably also throw an error instead of printing out if the `eventStore` is not set).

Comment: Updated to use `guard` and throw an error, as an better use of Swift 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure about the code, but I fixed the errors, I needed to still use the do-try-catch, but like so:

```
     do {
            try appDelegate!.eventStore!.saveReminder(reminder, commit: true) 
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you check an optional value for `nil`

```
if (appDelegate!.eventStore != nil) {
```

you have to unwrap it in case it's not `nil`

```
let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: appDelegate!.eventStore!)
```

A more suitable way is to use optional bindings

```
if let store = appDelegate!.eventStore {
 let reminder = EKReminder(eventStore: store)
  …
}
```

What is the purpose to declare `appDelegate` as optional?
The `AppDelegate` class exists in any application by default and could be never `nil`.